Radial Symmetry in Sculpt Mode does NOT work on Asymmetrical Mesh
I'm wondering if this is a bug or a limitation of the current sculpting tools.
I have a slightly asymmetrical mesh and I am trying to sculpt lines on the bottom of it in a fan-like pattern (shown below).

Unfortunately, the pattern comes out like this, where only a few lines are drawn (instead of the full 360 degree radial symmetry). I have the falloff mode set to "Sphere":

Now, if I set the falloff mode to "Projected", then it "appears" to draw the lines, however, they are drawn horribly wrong (the lines reverse their sculpt direction while passing over the mesh's normals, with some pointing up, some pointing down, but mostly just skewed sideways in a weird way.
"Sculpt Plane" is set to "Area Plane" and "Front Faces Only" is checked, but I have also tried a plethora of different combinations and nothing seems to work, so this is why I thought it is either a bug or a limitation. What are your thoughts? Thanks so much!


I thank God for showing me what was causing this issue. This is due to the mesh being both convex (pointing outward) and concave (pointing inward) at the same time. In this case, the mesh is convex in the Y-axis and is concave in the X-Axis. I have filed a bug report HERE and will update this answer with more details.
UPDATE: As Philipp Oeser observed, the radial strokes are distributed on a "flat" plane around the specified access which results in strokes missing areas that are non-flat. However, the effect can be mostly mitigated by switching the Brush Falloff from "Sphere" to "Projected" and checking the box for "Original Normal" under Advanced Brush Settings. However, you will still get flattening wherever the surface normal becomes perpendicular to the orthographic view, and the sculpt will actually invert wherever the surface normal changes completely (from concave to convex, or from convex to concave), which may be a current limitation of how the tool works.



